# Reduce redirects with RewriteMap

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, rewritemap

I have a RewriteMap in a file, and want to handle (ignore) optional trailing slahses. I would like to minimize the number of redirects in the trailing slash case. How do I change the apache-config?

Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName redirtest.localhost
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap test "txt:/tmp/redirects.txt"  #/old   /new
RedirectMatch ^/(.*?)/$ /$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${test:%1|NOT_PRESENT}  !NOT_PRESENT [NC]
RewriteRule .?                       ${test:%1} [NC,R=301]
```

result (ok):

```
curl -sIL 'http://redirtest.localhost/old?key=val&somemore=foobar' |grep Location 
Location: http://redirtest.localhost/new?key=val&somemore=foobar
```

Below works, but I would like to avoid the intermediate redirect:

```
curl -sIL 'http://redirtest.localhost/old/?key=val&somemore=foobar' |grep Location
Location: http://redirtest.localhost/old?key=val&somemore=foobar
Location: http://redirtest.localhost/new?key=val&somemore=foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteMap test "txt:/tmp/redirects.txt" 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^(.*\w)/?$
RewriteCond ${test:%1|NOT_PRESENT}  !NOT_PRESENT [NC]
RewriteRule .?                       ${test:%1} [NC,R=301]
RedirectMatch ^/(.*?)/$ /$1
```